# Web Part connections?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

It is possible to connect 3 document librarys to the same Web Part ?

```
DocLib A
   File - (lookUp 1)
DocLib B
   File - (lookUp 1)
DocLib C
   File - (lookUp 1)
```

all have the same columns with a lookup-column to a list.